# Can Tails Leak My IP?

Tags: anonymity, tails, deanonymization, ip-address, ip-address-leak

I know that by default all traffic is routed trough TOR, but can my IP leak when using Tails? What i mean is, for example, my machine gets hacked while using Tails and somebody who hacked me wants to find out my IP. Excluding MAC address wifi network name and other identifiers can the attacker find out my IP or does Tails secure/hide it?
EDIT: Also excluding TOR attacks/vulnerabilities (timing attacks, checking packet size at ISP/Entry Node and Exit etc.).

Comment: If somebody hacks your machine, and has access to it, then Tails can't protect you. Nothing can.

Comment: There are 2 Virtual Machines and one connects to the other to get internet access (windows and whoinx for example), then if windows machine gets hacked the attacker cant get my ip. I am sure there are other ways to secure your ip if you get infected.

Comment: If Tails is running inside a VM and that VM is running as a service inside Windows (perhaps inside VirtualBox), then yes, hacking your Windows account gives them access to everything running inside that account, including the Tails VM. Assuming they have root/admin Windows access, they effectively become you. (This all depends on what you mean by "hacked".)

Comment: I was talking about whonix and windows running in one machine not about tails inside windows. Anyway lets say that we have 2 separate machines one running whonix and other running linux. Linux gets internet access trough whonix machine and the whonix machine blocks all ports so its very difficult to hack it.

Comment: This is VERY broad